# How to use an inputdialog variable in a "for loop"?

Tags: function, variables, vim, input, for-loop

"I can't find out how to use a variable out of an inputdialog in a function or for loop.
Inputdialog is seen in as a string and I can't use it in a for loop or function.

p.e.:

```
if !exists("myvar")  
let myvar= "which variable?"   
endif   
let a = inputdialog(myvar) 

for n in range(1,3) 
 put = a
endfor
```

if p.e. 
var a = n
I expect this as output:

```
1
2
3
```

but it gives this as output:

```
n  
n   
n
```

("a" is seen as string and not as operator)

What did I wrong?
How can I let vim recognize the value of an inputdialog as operator and not as string?

Comment: But your code is correct, it prints what it should. I am not sure what are you trying to do, please edit and reformulate.

Comment: @lzap I reformulated the text. Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: What do expect `put = a` to do? It will put the contents of the var 'a' set with `inputdialog()` and if it was set to 'n' that's what will be put on the buffer. Why don't you use `put = n` if you want the values of 'n'? I'm afraid I'm not getting what you want to do.

Comment: @El Isra - I want to do more complex operations and let the user insert it by inputdialog. My question is "how can I send a variable from the inputdialog to a "for loop" and use it as variable and not as string?

Comment: So you want to *interpret* something? For user input this is pretty dangerous.

Comment: See `:help :exec` and `:help eval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the command

```
:put =a
```

to

```
:put =eval(a)
```

It is also possible to use

```
:exe 'put =' a
```

However, if the string stored in the `a` variable contains characters
interfering with Ex commands syntax or Command-line mode shortcuts, the above
command does not work correctly without escaping said characters.